# Multiple static IPs for a docker container

Tags: docker, centos

I have a lot of static IP. and I want to connect it docker container port 7179. (host os is centos)

`sudo docker run --network host -p 7179:7179 <docker_image>`

There are centos and go in container.

So, I make `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/` config for static IPs.

and `systemctl restart network`.

As the result, container occurs error like this

`System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate. Failed to connect to bus: Host is down`

Is it possible using host network with many static ip in docker container??

Comment: If you weren't using Docker, how would you attach a different static IP to each process?  If you're using host networking you can't use most of the Docker network configuration (for example that `-p` option is a no-op); do you have a specific need for it?

Comment: What's wrong with NAT / masquering the external IP packets to the network of the docker bridge?

Comment: I want to connect static IPs to only one single process. so I want to connect static IPs single container. @DavidMaze

Comment: I want to know that is it working static ip network setting in docker container when using host network?? @GuidoU.Draheim

Comment: If you're using the host network, there are no Docker network settings at all.  It's up to you to set the container process to listen to the specific IP address you want.